# IPreviewHandler throws uncatchable exception

Tags: c#, winforms, com

I've imported the COM interface `IPreviewHandler` into a WinForms app and am using it to display previews for various types of documents (I look up the GUID of the appropriate preview handler in the registry, then use `Activator.CreateInstance(guid)` to instantiate the specific COM class.

**This works** wonderfully for the vast majority of file types - Office formats, PDFs, videos, etc - however, after I instantiate the "Microsoft Windows TXT Preview Handler" `{1531d583-8375-4d3f-b5fb-d23bbd169f22}`, initialise it with a stream containing an ordinary .txt file, set the bounds of the preview window and then finally call `DoPreview()`, I get an exception that cannot be caught using try...catch:

```
try {
    Type comType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(guid);
    object handler = Activator.CreateInstance(comType);

    if (handler is IInitializeWithStream) {
        Stream s = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open);
        // this just passes the System.IO.Stream as the COM type IStream
        ((IInitializeWithStream)handler).Initialize(new StreamWrapper(s), 0);
    }
    else {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    RECT r = new RECT();
    r.Top = 0;
    r.Left = 0;
    r.Right = hostControl.Width;
    r.Bottom = hostControl.Height;

    ((IPreviewHandler)handler).SetWindow(hostControl.Handle, ref r);
    ((IPreviewHandler)handler).DoPreview();    // <-- crash occurs here
}
catch (Exception) {
    // this will never execute
}
```

When I step through with the debugger, the Visual Studio Hosting Process crashes. With no debugger, the application crashes without firing the `AppDomain.UnHandledException` or `Application.ThreadException` events.

I don't really mind that I can't preview plain text files using this technique (the working preview handlers for Office formats, etc are sufficient for my app's requirements), but I am concerned about having my app crash uncontrollably should the user select a .txt file. Is there any way I can catch this error and handle it gracefully? Better yet, is there some way I can overcome it and get the handler to work?

Comment: No type library.  How did you 'import' the interface declarations?

Comment: @Hans Passant: Manual declaration using `[ComImport]` and `[Guid]` attributes. See the source code on my blog: http://www.brad-smith.info/blog/archives/79

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I couldn't get the GetPreviewHandlerGUID() to recognize a .txt file and had to inject the GUID directly.  You can see what goes wrong when you use Project + Properties, Debug, tick Enable unmanaged code debugging.

The debugger will now stop on the problem and display

> `STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN encountered

The top of the call stack looks like this:

```
kernel32.dll!_UnhandledExceptionFilter@4()  + 0x1a368 bytes 
shell32.dll!___report_gsfailure()  + 0xc8 bytes 
shell32.dll!CRTFPreviewHandler::_StreamInCallback()  + 0x74 bytes   
msftedit.dll!CLightDTEngine::ReadPlainText()  + 0xed bytes  
msftedit.dll!CLightDTEngine::LoadFromEs()  + 0x202b3 bytes  
msftedit.dll!CTxtEdit::TxSendMessage()  + 0x1e25f bytes 
msftedit.dll!_RichEditWndProc@16()  + 0x13d bytes
```

The problem is located in the StreamInCallback() function.  It is called by the RichTextBox that's used to display the preview (msftedit.dll) to load the file.  The code in this callback function has a bug, it destroys the 'canary' that's used to detect that the stack frame got corrupted because of a buffer overrun.

This is part of the counter-measures that Microsoft took to prevent viruses from injecting themselves by buffer overruns.  The /GS compile option in Visual Studio for the C/C++ languages.  Once detected, the CRT very swiftly terminates the program.  This happens without an exception getting raised, the stack cannot safely be unwound because it was compromised.  Accordingly, the CLR cannot catch the exception.

This bug is specific to the TXT file viewer.  There's nothing you can do about it other than not using it.  Reporting this bug to connect.microsoft.com probably isn't useful, they'll close it as 'external'.  This is otherwise a subtle hint what can happen when you let unmanaged code run inside your program ;)

Comment: Thanks, your answer certainly sheds some light on it. I have observed that the Windows TXT Preview Handler is, in fact, not associated with the .txt extension on Windows 7, only on Vista. Perhaps MS realised that allowing third party apps to host this buggy handler was a bad idea? I might just blacklist that CLSID in my app.

Comment: what a great answer. Bradley Smith, did you write your own Handler for txt files? Or how you got around this issue?

Comment: The uncatchable Exception seems also to be thrown for *.reg *.bat and *.vbs Files.

Answer (score 2):

The real reason you're getting this problem is that you're creating the preview handler object **in-process**. The correct way is to create it **out-of-process**.

**DISCLOSURE** The following contains advertisement of my blog/code snippet.

See https://github.com/GeeLaw/PreviewHost for an example. Specifically, see [Line 219 of PreviewHandler.cs](https://github.com/GeeLaw/PreviewHost/blob/master/PreviewHost/Interop/PreviewHandler.cs#L219), where you have to pass `CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER` to `CoCreateInstance`. As explained in [one of my blog entries](https://geelaw.blog/entries/ipreviewhandlerframe-wpf-2-interop/#explanation), `Activator.CreateInstance` allows in-process server, which does not meet the expectation of preview handlers, since they must be created in the correct surrogate process, as documented [on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/preview-handlers#server-model-options).

Comment: When you host a preview handler, and let's say you view an Excel or Word file, does prevhost.exe start up for you?  Because for my attempt (which I've asked about here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62985123/how-to-host-a-preview-handler-in-a-dialog-without-having-focus-problems), prevhost does not start up, and I seem to encounter some focus problems as well.  Have you encountered issues like that?

Comment: @loop123123 "prevhost.exe" is just the default surrogate process for preview handlers implemented in DLL. Some preview handlers choose to implement their own local server. Office preview handlers are such an example. You will see "winword.exe" running when a Word document is being previewed in Explorer. It's expected.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I was able to get the TXT PreviewHandler working by compiling in x64 instead of `AnyCPU`.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 (64bit) so this answer won't apply if you are in a 32bit OS.

In Visual Studio 2010

- click on the `Configurations` drop-down list
- select `Configuration Manager...`
- click in the `Platform` cell next to your project
- select `New...` and select target platform `x64`
- copy settings from `AnyCPU` and away you go.

Answer (score 0):

Its very unlikely but can be the issue here - catch(Exception) will catch only exceptions of type of Exception - try using catch w/o any type filtering.

```
catch(Exception ex) {
   // Normal logging etc
}
catch
{
   // Exception of types other than System.Exception.
}
```

Comment: Rather unsurprisingly, this doesn't work. I'm also pretty sure that the CLR cannot, by definition, catch anything other than a `System.Exception`. Should some low-level exception occur, `Marshal` is supposed to throw a `COMException` or a `Win32Exception`.

Comment: I agree - there should have been COMException. FYI, I had read in J Ritcher book's that CLR does not mandate exception object to be of type System.Exception but languages (C#, Vb.NET) does not support it.

Another long shot for your problem - if your are using .NET4, check if you are coming across Corrupted State Exceptions - as they need marking your code with HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions attribute.

Comment: Still living in .NET 2.0 land, unfortunately. Might give this a try in an isolated project that targets .NET 4...

Comment: @VinayC Attempted to run the example under .NET 4 with the method decorated with that attribute. No change in behaviour, still crashes with no explanation.

Comment: Must be some nasty bug in native code that crashes the process - IMO, only crash dump will give you some idea about the issue but I am not expert here.
As far as your problem is concerned, a robust way will be to host Preview part in different AppDomain (or another process)

Comment: @VinayC: As of CLR 2, the runtime will wrap any exception object that doesn't derive from System.Exception in a System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeWrappedException (unless you explicitly turn it off).

Comment: @Mattias S - thanks for the info. I had read that piece in .NET Fx Applied Programming 10 years back! Planning to catch up now - had ordered CLR via C# 3rd Edition couple days back :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the solution to this problem. The thing is that the stream you're creating is either cleaned by the garbage collector or something else. If you call the initialize method using the stream created by the code below it should work:

```cs
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream stream;
    byte[] fileData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
    System.IntPtr hGlobal = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocHGlobal(fileData.Length);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(fileData, 0, hGlobal, fileData.Length);
    NativeMethods.CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hGlobal, false, out stream);
    //[DllImport("ole32.dll")]
    //internal static extern int CreateStreamOnHGlobal(IntPtr hGlobal, bool fDeleteOnRelease, out IStream ppstm);
```

I’m using the code above in a Windows Forms Application explicitly set to 32bit (x86) and running in Single-Threaded Apartments mode.

Credit goes to Sherlock Homes (http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.interop/2010-09/msg00003.html)